# How to set up only circle size(in xml)?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, shapes

I want to set up circle size, but I don't want resize other elements in layer list.
I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/drawer_color" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#1b2727"
            android:centerColor="#1a2a29"
            android:startColor="#154440"
            android:type="linear"
            android:angle="90"/>
        <size
            android:height="600dp"
            android:width="600dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dip"
            android:color="@color/drawer_ring_color" />
    </shape>
</item>


</layer-list>
```

What I found: [image]

And what I want to see: [image]

How to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this do not works this way, your drawable will take the size of view where you use that drawable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `padding` in your code.

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/drawer_color" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="100dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="100dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```